# Объединить элементы массива в группы

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется массив текстовых переменных

```
string[] str_arr = new string[]{"qw","we","er","rt","ty","yu"}
```

требуется из этого массива получить такой

```
{"qw we","er rt","ty yu"}
```

или такой

```
{"qw we er","rt ty yu"}
```

т.е. объединить отдельные элементы в группы. причем заранее неизвестно сколько должно быть элементов в группе.

Никак не могу найти красивое решение.

Comment: По какому принципу элементы объединяются в группы?

Comment: Определенное число соседних элементов. если 2 то объединятся первый и второй, третий и четвертый, пятый и шестой. Если 3 то первый, второй и третий и так далее

Comment: Т.е. количество элементов в каждой группе задает пользователь?

Comment: Да, число элементов в группе заранее не известно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если число элементов в каждой группе одинаково - вычислим номер группы, сгруппируем по номеру группы, сджойним через пробел:

```
    const int groupSize = 2;
    var groupStr =
        str_arr.Select((item, index) => 
                new {item, Index = index/groupSize})
            .GroupBy(s => s.Index, s => s.item)
            .Select(x => string.Join(" ", x))
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: `index/groupSize` уже даёт целое число. В чём смысл `Math.Ceiling((decimal) ... )`?

Comment: Да, особо нет смысла. Привычка :) Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё одно возможное решение — использовать библиотеку [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) и метод `Batch`:

```
str_arr.Batch(n).Select(seq => string.Join(" ", seq))
```